# The leaflet is not displayed

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am new to JavaScript. The leaflet on the page doesn't display the map until I change the .leaflet-container property {
overflow: ;}, you can see it in image2. How can I fix this? Thank you!
CSS

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"  />
<style>
    body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    html, body, #map {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

HTML

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

JS

```
</body>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script>
        var map = L.map.invalidateSize();
        L.tileLayer(
            'https://api.maptiler.com/maps/streets/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?key=ekfefkerdkdfk2', 
            {attribution: '<a href="https://www.maptiler.com/copyright/" target="_blank">&copy; MapTiler</a> <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright" target="_blank">&copy; OpenStreetMap contributors</a>'}
        ).addTo(map);
    </script>
```

[image: image2]
[image: image1]

Answer (score 1):

Replace `var map = L.map.invalidateSize();` with

```
var map = L.map('map', {
    center: [51.505, -0.09],
    zoom: 13
});
```

If it still not work check if you overwrite `div` in some of your CSS classes. Else create a sample on https://leafletjs.com/edit

Comment: I changed var map = L.map.invalidateSize(); The map showed up in Plunker, but still doesn't show up on my page.

Comment: Then you overwrite it with some css style. In the "Elements" Tab of the developer tools (F12) you can see which styles are added to the map container

Comment: @Aliaksei.Statkevich make example on https://codesandbox.io